# Link to public folder

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

Say I create a folder in an S3 bucket, upload some files to the folder, and set them all public. How could I go about linking to this folder, so that others could simply browse the folder and choose a file to download?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer [**here**](http://github.com/adam-p/s3-file-list-page). In
short

1. Add grantee "Everyone" with list permission to bucket.
2. Add [**Amazon S3 bucket listing**](http://aws.amazon.com/code/Amazon-S3/1713)
3. visit `http://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/list.html`

Comment: You didn't ask to allow access to the entire bucket, just one folder